# Piping output to grep

Tags: grep, pipe

I've got this line in my bash script:

```
./tg/tg -c $THIS_DIR/tg/config 2>&1 | grep ".\+"
```

But it doesn't work. `tg` is running and producing output continuously (means doesn't terminate) and I just want to filter some of the results, but even when I use general `".\+"` pattern it doesn't work. I'm also sure when removing `| grep ".\+"` I get the output. How may I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of "*greping*" though a continuant input - use `--line-buffered` option:

```
./tg/tg -c $THIS_DIR/tg/config 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered ".\+"
```

---

> **`--line-buffered`**
>                 Use line buffering on output.  This can cause a performance penalty.